# Help me locate a passage regarding driving out the Canaanites before Israel

Tags: old-testament, verse-identification

I have embedded in my memory that somewhere in the Old Testament there is a passage, where God says something to effect of:

> If you knew how evil these Canaanites were, you would not wonder why I drove them out / destroyed them.

For the life of me I can not remember the exact wording in any language I know.

Comment: [Gen. 15:16](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/gen/15/16/t_conc_15016) (re: Amorites)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a verse search question.

Comment: I'm not opposed to verse identification questions like this, but without more details (especially a listing of several passages you've found and rejected, and *why*), it's difficult or impossible to objectively answer.

Comment: Try [Deuteronomy 9:1-5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy+9%3A1-5&version=NRSV) and [Deuteronomy 18:9-14](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy+18%3A9-14&version=NRSV).

Answer (score 3):

[Deut. 9 [NASB]](http://biblehub.com/nasb/deuteronomy/9.htm)

> 1 “Hear, O Israel! You are crossing over the Jordan today to go in to dispossess nations greater and mightier than you, great cities
>   fortified to heaven, 2 a people great and tall, the sons of the Anakim,
>   whom you know and of whom you have heard it said, ‘Who can stand
>   before the sons of Anak?’ 3 “Know therefore today that it is the LORD
>   your God who is crossing over before you as a consuming fire. He will
>   destroy them and He will subdue them before you, so that you may drive
>   them out and destroy them quickly, just as the LORD has spoken to you.
>
> **4 “Do not say in your heart when the LORD your God has driven them out before you, ‘Because of my righteousness the LORD has brought
>   me in to possess this land,’ but it is because of the wickedness of
>   these nations that the LORD is dispossessing them before you. 5 “It is
>   not for your righteousness or for the uprightness of your heart that
>   you are going to possess their land, but it is because of the
>   wickedness of these nations that the LORD your God is driving them out
>   before you, in order to confirm the oath which the LORD swore to your
>   fathers, to Abraham, Isaac and Jacob.**

Answer (score 0):

> When the Lord your God cuts off before you the nations whom you go in to dispossess, and you dispossess them and dwell in their land, take care that you be not ensnared to follow them, after they have been destroyed before you, and that you do not inquire about their gods, saying, ‘How did these nations serve their gods?—that I also may do the same.’ You shall not worship the Lord your God in that way, for every abominable thing that the Lord hates they have done for their gods, for they even burn their sons and their daughters in the fire to their gods. (Deut. 12:29)

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I'm positive that this passage isn't it.